# Calling a PHP function by onclick event

Tags: php, function

I am trying to call a function by "onclick" event of the button.
When I do that it shows error message.
Can anybody help me out on this so that when I click on the button it should call the function and execute it.

**My PHP code is:**

```
<?php
    function hello() {
        echo "Hello";
    }
    echo "<input type='button' name='Release' onclick= hello(); value='Click to Release'>";
?>
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Use jQuery AJAX. It's not impossible if you really need to run a PHP script.

Comment: **try this:** `onclick="<?= myFunction(); ?>"` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First quote your JavaScript:

```
onclick="hello();"
```

Also you can't call a PHP function from JavaScript;
you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hello()
{
alert ("hello");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 31):

The onClick attribute of html tags only takes Javascript but not PHP code. However, you can easily call a PHP function from within the Javascript code by using the JS document.write() function - effectively calling the PHP function by "writing" its call to the browser window: Eg.

```
onclick="document.write('<?php //call a PHP function here ?>');"
```

Your example:

```
    <?php
          function hello(){
              echo "Hello";
          }
    ?>

<input type="button" name="Release" onclick="document.write('<?php hello() ?>');" value="Click to Release">
```

Comment: How can this possibly work? Where did all the up-votes come from?

Comment: This also won't work for me... It will replace the whole html code with "<?php hello() ?>"

Answer (score 2):

Executing PHP functions by the onclick event is a cumbersome task and near impossible.

Instead you can redirect to another PHP page.

Say you are currently on a page one.php and you want to fetch some data from this php script process the data and show it in another page i.e. two.php you can do it by writing the following code
`<button onclick="window.location.href='two.php'">Click me</button>`

Answer (score 2):

**onclick event to call a function**

```
  <strike> <input type="button" value="NEXT"  onclick="document.write('<?php //call a function here ex- 'fun();' ?>');" />    </strike>
```

it will surely help you

it take a little more time than normal but wait it will work

Answer (score 2):

**In Your HTML**

```
<input type="button" name="Release" onclick="hello();" value="Click to Release" />
```

**In Your JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hello(){
        alert('Your message here');
    }
</script>
```

**If you need to run PHP in JavaScript You need to use JQuery Ajax Function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hello(){
    $.ajax(
{     
 type:    'post',
 url:     'folder/my_php_file.php',
 data:    '&id=' + $('#id').val() + '&name=' +     $('#name').val(),
 dataType: 'json',
 //alert(data);
 success: function(data) 
 {
  //alert(data);
 }   
});
}
</script>
```

**Now in your my_php_file.php file**

```
<?php 
    echo 'hello';
?>
```

Good Luck !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

probably the `onclick` handler should read `onclick='hello();'` instead of `onclick=hello();`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute PHP functions from JavaScript.

PHP runs on the server before the browser sees it. PHP outputs HTML and JavaScript.

When the browser reads the HTML and JavaScript it executes it.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this html code it will surely help you**

```
<input type="button" value="NEXT"  onclick="document.write('<?php //call a function here ex- 'fun();' ?>');" />
```

one limitation is that it is taking more time to run so wait for few seconds it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
  function runMyFunction() {
    echo 'I just ran a php function';
  }

  if (isset($_GET['hello'])) {
    runMyFunction();
  }
?>

Hello there!

<a href='index.php?hello=true'>Run PHP Function</a>

</body>
</html>
```