# PHP Script in OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, php, html

This **IS** a duplicate from [Calling a php function by onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451070/calling-a-php-function-by-onclick-event), but I have a question on it. The answer I had a question on is by timpanix, and basically it won't work.

He said to execute some PHP code in a On Click event do this:

```
onclick="document.write('<?php //call a PHP function here ?>');"
```

and call the PHP function. Yet whenever I try it:

```
<button id="profileinformationbutton" input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="document.write('<?php profileupdated() ?>');"> Update Profile </button>
```

it prints out `');" > Update Profile`, yet I have no clue why. It is inside of a form, and the PHP function looks like this:

```
<?php
    function profileupdated() {
?>
        <div id="profileupdated"> Profile Updated </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Why would the code be displaying this? Please help! :) Thank You.

### EDIT

The code does not seem to be writing `Profile Updated` to the page, any idea why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: escape the double quotes inside your php function to fix your problem

Comment: You're echo div with double quote attribute inside double quote attribute. The php code will not execute on the client but on the server before html is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function profileupdated() {

        echo "<div id='profileupdated'> Profile Updated </div>";

    }
```

Also if you only want to print this value to your tag why you're using function? Assign it to a variable.

like

```
$myVar = '<div id="profileupdated"> Profile Updated </div>';
```

Then use this variable where you want?

you should echo or return your function body. Carefull! I changed quotes!

Comment: Updated with one more little question :)

Comment: Where did you define your function? Another page, in class .. ?

Comment: @hakkikonu You're missing a `<` before your `echo` statement in your second example...

Comment: Thank You! :) BTW for the variable would I just do this? onclick="document.write('<?php $variablehere ?>');"

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP function is writing to the page already, rendering the document.write (javascript) useless. Try this:

```
<?php 
    function profileupdated() {
        return "<div id='profileupdated'>Profile updated</div>";
    } 
?>
```

I do want to note though that you might want to consider a cleaner way of doing this: If you just want to display a fixed text ("Profile updated"), stick to pure client-side Javascript.

Otherwise (if there's logic to be done server-side), you might want to decouple server and client and use an AJAX call and JSON to transfer your data.

Answer (score -1):

PHP is a server side programming language, you are executing the JavaScript on the client side.
If you want to call a PHP script from your JavaScript you need Ajax, f.e. jQuery.